# Sending a message to a router's IP address?

Tags: android, sockets, ip-address, router

I am trying to make an Android app that is supposed to send messages between two clients via their IP address.

I currently have a set up that enables a server that runs in the background that listens for incoming messages and its address is the device's IP address. However, I am not able to reach this server unless both devices are connected to the same network.

I want to know if there was a way to send the message to the router, which will then send the message to the specified device via its port number or another specifier, instead of sending the message directly to the device's IP address.

I have been searching and found that some instant messaging programs have a similar kind of set up and I read that Net Send used to do a similar job in previous versions of Windows. I have not been able to find anything that relates to doing this on Android though. At this point, I just want to know if this is possible and if someone could guide me in the right direction. I am just not sure if this idea is possible. 
I want to try my best not to have a single dedicated server that all messages are sent to, then from there the server distributes the messages appropriately. I would rather have each device run its independent server in the background so it can be reached from any other device globally.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to set up port forwarding on the router for the server hosting this application.

There may be complications, depending on how the application works. If it does use broadcasts, you are not going to be able to get it to work as you have described. If the application uses an IP address and port, then port forwarding on the server's router will probably work, but you may need to adjust settings in any firewall protecting the server.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but the server will not be a single dedicated server that handles all communication requests. the server is a background listener for incoming communication requests that run independent on every device that will run the app. So setting up port forwarding will not be possible on every single device that installs the app. I am thinking the solution might be sending messages to the public ip address of the device, along with the private ip address so that the messages can be directed by the router to the specified device? Or is that much more than a simple app's work?

Comment: If you have a bunch of devices on various networks which are hidden behind NAT, the only way to make this work is to have a central server to which each device connects. You can't control all the NAT routers and firewalls that each remote may have, but you can control a NAT router and firewall at a site with a single server. Hosting services would be ideal for something like this.

Comment: I understand that a single server with port forwarding is more or less the ideal way to get this done. I just have to convince the person I'm making this app for since he insists on not having a single server for all this to work from. Thanks for your help though. I will be back to update as I gather more information.